# How to open an Android Settings Dialog from another Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, wifi, start-activity

My app scans for Wifi networks and displays them in a GridView.
When I click on an item I check which type of security it uses by reading through ScanResult.capabilities.
If it's an open network I am able to connect to it by adding it to my WifiConfiguration, enabling it and calling reconnect.

If the network requires a password, I would like **one of these two behaviours** :

1. My Activity should display the default dialog box with the SSID, Password field, "Show password" checkbox, Cancel and Connect buttons.

or

2. Go to the WifiSettings by calling startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
   But go straight to the window described above without having to click on the item again on that window. This would probably mean triggering an onClick but without clicking.

**Is there any way to access this Dialog box from another Activity?**

Answer (score 0):

Same question came up years ago - unfortunately without answer:
[How to invoke system dialog for "Connect to" secured network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316952/how-to-invoke-system-dialog-for-connect-to-secured-network)

A really bad hack (that should work) is to call the `WifiDialog` by including the `android.jar`. But this is a really bad solution as it dramatically increases the app's size and you do not rely on the specific `WiFiDialog` for the API level on the current device.

Alternatively, you have to implement this [dialog](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/android-6.0.1_r21/src/com/android/settings/wifi/WifiDialog.java) yourself.

By the way, there was an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6856) opened but unfortunately it is marked as obsolete. But nothing has changed.

Comment: Hi @Timo, thank you for your suggestions. I think I ended up opening a custom Dialog reproducing the basic behavior of the WifiDialog, but it certainly was a pain. Too bad no move is being made towards solving this issue.